# How to include Gradle subproject into composite build?

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I'm trying to use composite builds of Gradle (3.5) for the 1st time and I need to include a library which is a subproject of another project (both in Java):

```
> gradle projects
:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'projects'
+--- ...
+--- Project ':common'    <-- this is a library I need
+--- ...
```

Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/composite_builds.html) gives examples of single-module projects only but specifying the path to `common` directory directly (i.e. `includeBuild '../../projects/common'`) is not an option as it ends up with expectable error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
...
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':common'.
> Could not find method sourceSets() for arguments [build_9fu2oyxlwh2mr0i7k6l680fpz$_run_closure1@66e1cb67] on project ':common' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Another supposedly appropriate feature is [substitutions](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions) but I don't see how to apply it to my case. I also haven't seen any [statements](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_substitution_limitations) in documentation telling that such an including is not possible. Depending on the whole `projects` is not right also because it is quite heavy repo.

So the question is:
How to declare a dependency on certain subproject in Gradle composite build?